# source tree connection to bitbucket.local

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to clone remote repository from bitbucket and getting the following error message when inserting URL: This is not a valid source path/ URL
Output: 
Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false ls-remote https://bitbucket.localnet/projects/SomeProject -v
Output: 
Error: fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.localnet/projects/SomeProject/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.localnet

Command: hg identify extensions.hgext.hgsubversion=! https://bitbucket.localnet/projects/SomeProject
Output: 
Error: abort: error: getaddrinfo failed

Answer (score 1):

Your computer doesn't know how to resolve "bitbucket.localnet". You'll either need to provide the IP in a hosts file; give its IP to DNS and have DNS resolve this properly; or use a hostname that does resolve.